# I just can't uninstall genymotion from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I installed Genymotion in my Ubuntu 16.04

But now I want to uninstall it.

I tried executing

```
./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall
```

But that returned

```
bash: ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin: Permission denied
```

How can I uninstall genymotion from my Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like you're only missing `sudo`
Try:

```
sudo ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall
```

Or if that didn't work, try with `sh` like this:

```
sudo sh ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing works. Everythings I found on internet try this, but nothing could solve my problem. Finally I erase my hard drive and install Ubuntu again to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Remove all virtual Android devices and data from genymotion program.

Step 2: Open Terminal and delete installation directory as superuser (when you install any .bin file program it get installed for all user)

```
cd /opt
sudo rm -r genymobile
```

Step 3: Remove configure folders and file.

```
cd /home/(your user folder)
rm -fr .Genymotion
```

Step 4: open menu editor from **Settings Manager** and delete Genymotion launcher, if it is still in the menu.

Comment: where is "menu editor" in settings?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
./genymotion-X.X.X-linux_x64.bin -u -d <your genymotion directory>
```

(my directory is `~/genymotion`)

Comment: if it doesn't work  ./genymotion-X.X.X-linux_x64.bin --help will help you ,dont't forget to remove genymotion's directory

Answer (score 1):

You can try command `chmod +x genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin`, And then try `./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall`. I hope it work well.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to your downloads folder where you've downloaded the genymotion installer. (The installer filename is something like "genymotion-3.2.1-linux_x64.bin".)

Step 2: Right click on the directory and click "Open in Terminal".

Step 3: In terminal type the following command to uninstall genymotion:

```
sudo ./genymotion-3.2.1-linux_x64.bin -d {install path} --uninstall
```

Note: The installer version may vary; change it according to the version you've installed. The install path in my case was:

```
/opt/genymobile/
```

Replace the install path if you've installed it in some other directory.

The full command, in my case, looked like this:

```
sudo ./genymotion-3.2.1-linux_x64.bin -d /opt/genymobile/ --uninstall
```

Step 4: To delete the genymobile configuration file from your home folder, open terminal and type the following commands:

```
cd
sudo rm -r .Genymobile/
```

Step 5: Eventually, if you want to completely remove virtualbox and its configuration files type the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
```

Reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Xh3om4Qfqg&ab_channel=TiwoSatriatama

Comment: Hello. A link only answer is not an answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1216443)