# Unable to remove Geanymotion from my pc...I'm doing it wrong?

Tags: command-line, sudo, uninstall

Hi guys I'm tryng to remove geanymotion from my pc but it's always impossibile for some error or the terminal say to me that there is no such file or directory for geanymotion...can someone help me?

**Just tryed with that:**

```
(sudo) apt-get --purge remove genymotion

(sudo) ./genymotion-2.7.2_x64.bin --uninstall

(sudo) ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall

/home/egavs/Desktop/genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall
```

Same problem with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815840/i-just-cant-uninstall-genymotion-from-ubuntu-16-04) procedure.

Thanks to all in advice! =)

Comment: How did you installed geany motion. If you installed recently via terminal check out the history in terminal and update it here.

Comment: @AUmarMukthar Not recently like 10 month ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling Genymotion using synaptic package manager
Install synaptic using command `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
Then open synaptic and search for Genymotion and uninstall the installed packages